# python script sytax error

Tags: arcpy, syntax

I keep getting this syntax error and don't know why. Brand new to python.

```
# Opens a feature class from a geodatabase and prints the spatial reference
 
import arcpy
 
featureClass = "C:/Users/Travis Shooks/Documents/script/test.gdb/us_cities"
 
# Describe the feature class and get its spatial reference   
desc = arcpy.Describe(featureClass)
spatialRef = desc.spatialReference

# Print the spatial reference name
print spatialRef.Name
```

Comment: Paste here this error log.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  As a new user, please take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour).  All coding questions should always include the environment, the exact software release(s), the code, and the complete error message (in context to the code snippet).

Answer (score 4):

Python is case sensitive. You need to use `print spatialRef.name` following the [SpatialReference](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/spatialreference.htm) documentation.

```
# Opens a feature class from a geodatabase and prints the spatial reference

import arcpy

featureClass = "C:/Users/Travis Shooks/Documents/script/test.gdb/us_cities"

# Describe the feature class and get its spatial reference   
desc = arcpy.Describe(featureClass)
spatialRef = desc.spatialReference

# Print the spatial reference name
print spatialRef.name
```

As a side note, you can shorten this to a one-liner if you prefer:

```
import arcpy

featureClass = "C:/Users/Travis Shooks/Documents/script/test.gdb/us_cities"

print arcpy.Describe(featureClass).spatialReference.name
```